# SQLITE Is it possible to calculate the length of the longest increasing subsequence also referred to as sortation percent?

Tags: c++, sqlite

With the latest version of Sqlite, Is it possible to calculate the length of the longest increasing subsequence, also referred to as sortation percent, using a sqlite UDF, user defined function?

October 15,2012 edit as requested by @Code-Guru.

Following the project gurus's example sequence of -- 1,2,3,4,3,5,6,7,8,10 -- the numeric sorted ascending subsequence is found to be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10 using an automatic variable containing the most recent monotically increasing sequence member value and traversing the array sequentially. As a result, the length of the sorted numeric ascending subsequence is 9. The length of the entire sequence is 10. So, the sortation percentage is (9/10) * 100% = 90%. Thank you.

Comment: The sortation percent term  is used in data profiler protype tools. Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain more explicitly what subsequence you are asking about?

Comment: @Code-Guru, The longest increasing subsequence we are referring to is the longest contiguous increasing subsequence

Comment: Repeating the exact same words doesn't clarify what you mean. Can you give an example?

Comment: @Code-Guru, I will try to provide an example early next week when I ask the DATA QUALITY PROFILER TOOL project guru for a concrete example of the longest increasing subsequence known in the data quality tool industry as SORTATION percentage!!!

Comment: @Code-Guru, I asked the project guru for an example of the SORTATION percentage. For Example , the project guru says the sequence -- 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10 has a numeric ascending SORTATION percentage of 90 percent. The project guru asks us to implement this calculation in O(linear) time. Thank you.

Comment: Given the example list, how do you calculate SORTATION percentage? Can you describe how you would do this with pencil, paper, and a calculator?

Comment: If you are still looking for a solution to your problem, you should edit your question to include this information, rather than continue to post comments.

Comment: @Code-Guru, I just edited the solution to include this information. Thank you for all of your help in asking the purient problem formulation questions.

Comment: I don't think [purient](https://www.google.com/search?q=purient&rls=com.microsoft:en-us&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1) is the correct word...

Comment: @Code-Guru, I meant to say pertinent. I was simultaneously posting to another person about my weekend adventures with women. I agree with you that prurient is not the correct word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlite does not have any functionality that implements longest increasing subsequence, so you will need a user defined function

You can sort by function results.  I don't believe UDFs are treated any differently in this respect.

Here is an example of how you would use a function (user defined or not) to order your query results.

```
sqlite> create table foo(a);
sqlite> create table foobar(a);
sqlite> create table fubar(a);
sqlite> select name, length(name) as len from sqlite_master;
foo|3
foobar|6
fubar|5
sqlite> select name, length(name) as len from sqlite_master order by len;
foo|3
fubar|5
foobar|6
```

Comment: Sorting using ORDER BY LEN requires partial and/or total ordering of the sequence. For example, if the sequence is 1, 4 , 7, 10,

Comment: Sorting using ORDER BY LEN requires partial and/or total ordering of the sequence. Therefore sortation percent can be only one of two values 0% or 100%. As a counterexample, if the sequence is -----------------1, 4 , 7, 10, 12, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 15, 16 then the length of the longest increasing subsequence is 11 --------------- (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 15, 16) and therefore the sortation percentage in this case would be 100 * ( 11 / 16 ) %. Please let me know how we should handle 75% sortation percent using SQLITE. Thank you.

Comment: @Frank I was not trying to demonstrate how to implement "sortation."  I only was showing that if you implement it as a user defined function, you should be able to use it with `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Frank sqlite does not have any functionality that implements longest increasing subsequence, so you will need a user defined function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @TomKerr,  and comments on longest increasing subsequence. I will accept your answer in 5 minutes.